# After running npm run eject project entry point is not changing

Tags: react-native

I am new to react native. I have two project setup I installed by using:

```
1. create-react-native-app project1.
 2. create-react-native-app project2.
```

After running  **npm run eject** project1  entry point has been changed to index.js from app.js, but in the project2 no change has occurred for the entry points. I mean, index.js has not created why this is happening? Although both have a new android and ios folder. What should be the reason?

node version is: 8.12.0
npm version is: 6.4.1

Comment: Why are you running `eject`? If you don't know then you most likely should not run `eject`

Comment: then what should I do??? I am running eject to get those android and ios folders. it was working fine and crearting index.js with this code below:-

import React from 'react';

import App from './App';

AppRegistry.registerComponent('sandipReact', () => App);

but nothing is happening now

Comment: with `create-react-app` you use `Expo`, follow this guide: https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/getting-started you should only be ejecting if you need to write Java or Objective-C or need to use a library that utilizes Java or Objective-C